# Using alive-progress with List comprehension

Tags: python, progress-bar, list-comprehension

Is there an easy way to use alive_bar from alive_progress in list comprehension? I've just been sticking the operation I want to perform in a function, and passing it the item and `bar`. For example:

```
from alive_progress import alive_bar

def do_stuff(x, bar):
    # do some stuff with x here
    bar()
    return x
with alive_bar(len(list1)) as bar:
    list2 = [do_stuff(x, bar) for x in list1]
```

I get the sense this is a bit overcomplicated, and definitely repetitive; is there a way to get similar behavior without making a bunch of functions like this?

Comment: I didn't get any error running your code and the progress bar looked fine to me. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Not getting any errors, just can't shake the feeling that this isn't a very efficient way to use it.

Comment: IMO it looked completely fine. Why are you feeling this is not efficient or repetitive?

Comment: My thought was that the `bar` object should be modified to return the value somehow, which I guess is more of a feature request. And it turns out that in the newest version you are essentially able to do that, using `alive_it`. [Details on alive_it](https://github.com/rsalmei/alive-progress#auto-iterating--new-in-20)

Comment: Looks like the implementation of `alive_it` achieves something very similar to `tqdm`. If that looks more elegant for you, you can directly use `alive_it`, no?

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm doing going forward!

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments above, I ended up finding the answer to this in the new version of `alive_progress`. The `alive_it` object is able to take a list of iterables, so there isn't the need to wrap the list comprehension in it's own function.

Example using `alive_it`:

```
from alive_progress import alive_it
list1 = list(range(1,1000000))
list2 = [x ** 2 for x in alive_it(list1)]
```